# Component-preload.js generated with comments

Tags: gruntjs, sapui5

I'm working on some performance aspects for my app and, as a consequence, trying to remove the comments from the `Component-preload.js` file generated when building the app (I'm basically trying to uglify the component-preload)

To do that, I firstly tried to use the `"@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build"` as in its documentation is stated that there's an uglify, but unfortunately it doesn't remove the comments.

Now, I'm working with external plugins to be able to achieve this, but it seems is just "impossible".

This is my `gruntfile.js` for the moment:

```js
"use strict";

// Initial standard SAP Plugin
grunt.loadNpmTasks("@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build");

// Copy plugin configuration
var copyConfig = { 
  copy: {
    main: {
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'webapp/controller',
      src: '**',
      dest: 'webapp/aux',
    }
  }       
};
grunt.config.merge(copyConfig);
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-copy");

// Uglify plugin configuration
var uglifyConfig = {
  uglify: {
    dist: {
      options:{
        mangle:false
      },
      output: {
        comments: false
      },
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'webapp/controller',
        src: '**/*.js',
        dest: 'webapp/controller'
      }]
    }
  }
};  
grunt.config.merge(uglifyConfig);
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");

// Move plugin configuration
var moveConfig = { 
  move: {
    main: {
      src: 'webapp/aux/*',
      dest: 'webapp/controller/'
    }
  }
};
grunt.config.merge(moveConfig);
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-move");

// Custom clean plugin configuration
var cleanConfig = {
  clean: {
    custom: {
      src: 'webapp/aux'
    }
  }
};
grunt.config.merge(cleanConfig);
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-clean");

grunt.registerTask("default", [
  "clean",
  "lint",
  "copy",
  "uglify",
  "build",
  "move",
  "clean:custom"
]);
```

As you can see, I'm basically:

- Copying the sources with comments.
- Uglifying the original ones.
- Calling the build ( expecting that it uses the uglified sources to generated the `Component-preload.js` without comments )
- Restoring the ones that have comments into the "Controller" folder again.

At this point, I don't know which files is the IDE using to generate the `Component-preload.js` because I've even tried to do a build with:

1. Move: Moving the files from the "Controller" folder to an aux one.
2. Build: Expecting the build to crash or at least, not having any controller in the Component-preload.js

But the result from this test is that `Component-preload.js` is created and it contains the controller code, so it seems like before starting the whole procedure, the IDE saves a copy of all files.

Could you kindly help me understanding this? Or at least, how can I remove comments from the generated `Component-preload.js` file??

Thanks in advance and sorry if I haven't explained anything very clear.

Kr,
Pedro.

Comment: Are you able to access SAP's github? There is a repository "custdev-sapui5-infra-util" where you could find a grunt tasks which generates this preload without mentioned issue.

Comment: [grunt-stripcomments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-stripcomments) task to remove comments.

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych I'd say that I can check SAP's github, but not sure, do you have the URL to that repository? I've been able to find it.

Comment: @santhosh Thanks for your reply, but I already tried that plugin, the problem is the same than with the uglify one, comments are removed from the files that I use in the src configuration for that plugin, but it doesn't work with the "Component-preload.js"

Comment: @Xnail https://github.wdf.sap.corp/D053370/custdev-sapui5-infra-util/

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately I'm not able to see that URL, I get a "This site can’t be reached" message.